# vba nested error handling

Tags: vba, error-handling

I am trying to understand how to set up error-handling for the situation cited below. Sub A has error handling for its own context. However it calls Sub B which creates database connection, resultsets etc which it cleans up in its error handler. The way it stands, it seems only ErrorHandler A is active throughout. How can I activate ErrorHandler B when B is called and revert back to error-handling after B returns.

Thanks

```
Sub A
' Preps for database access
On Error GoTo ErrorHandlerA

B
.
.

Exit Sub
ErrorHandlerA:
...
Resume
End Sub

Sub B
' Does database access stuff

On Error ErrorHandlerB

cleanUp:
con.close
rs.close

Exit Sub
ErrorHandlerB:
GoTo cleanup

End Sub
```

Comment: Typically you have each error handler deal with errors within it's own Function or Sub. However, in cases where 'A' depends on 'B', then I would make 'B' a Function so I could return a 'pass/fail' status to 'A'.  And you may have an issue in 'B' where you branch to 'cleanup' if your objects were not opened (i.e. if RS not opened, then error, you will get into a loop as it will keep calling the error handler). Yes, I realize that is just sample code...

Comment: *it seems only ErrorHandler A is active throughout* what do you mean exactly? If you break on the `GoTo cleanUp` instruction under `ErrorHandlerB`, does the breakpoint not get hit when there's an error in `B`? Please [edit] your question to clarify what behavior you're expecting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> Exit Sub
> ErrorHandlerA:
> ...
> Resume
> End Sub
> ```

`Resume` here, resumes normal execution (clears "error handling mode") and jumps back to the instruction that caused the error. Presumably (hopefully?) the `...` contains code that makes the previously-failing call, succeed.

> ```
> cleanUp:
> con.close
> rs.close
>
> Exit Sub
> ErrorHandlerB:
> GoTo cleanup
>
> End Sub
> ```

Here you're `GoTo`-jumping outside the error-handling subroutine, **without resuming to normal execution**, so the instructions under the `cleanUp` line label execute in an error-handling context. That should be `Resume cleanUp`, not `GoTo`.

The `Exit Sub` statement leaves the scope, which clears the error state and implicitly resumes to normal execution. Here's a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
Public Sub Test()
On Error GoTo A
    DoSomething
    Debug.Print "After DoSomething: " & Err.Number
    Exit Sub
A:
    Debug.Print "Inside Test[A]: " & Err.Number
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomething()
On Error GoTo A

    Err.Raise 5

B:
    Debug.Print "Inside DoSomething[B]: " & Err.Number
    Exit Sub
A:
    Debug.Print "Inside DoSomething[A]: " & Err.Number
    Resume B
End Sub
```

Running the `Test` procedure produces this output:

```
Inside DoSomething[A]: 5
Inside DoSomething[B]: 0
After DoSomething: 0
```

Changing the `Resume B` instruction for a `GoTo B` produces this output:

```
Inside DoSomething[A]: 5
Inside DoSomething[B]: 5
After DoSomething: 0
```

As you can see, as the error was handled in `DoSomething`, error state is reset when execution returns to `Test`, and the handler in the `Test` procedure is never triggered.

If you want to propagate the error to the caller, you have a number of options:

- **Don't handle errors in the called procedure**. In the above example this means `DoSomething` wouldn't have an `On Error` statement; any run-time errors would "bubble up" the call stack, and the output would look like this now:

  ```
  Inside Test[A]: 5
  ```

  You would typically do this when it's the calling code that has the knowledge of what the best course of action would be (e.g. display a `MsgBox` to the user, or log the error, etc.).
- **Handle errors, and then re-raise them**. In your example this means moving (or copying) the cleanup code into the `ErrorHandlerB` subroutine, and calling `Err.Raise Err.Number` instead of `Resume`. Or you keep the `GoTo` and then the cleanup subroutine can do `If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number` to effectively re-throw the error for the caller to also handle. In other words:

  ```
  Public Sub Test()
  On Error GoTo A
      DoSomething
      Debug.Print "After DoSomething: " & Err.Number
      Exit Sub
  A:
      Debug.Print "Inside Test[A]: " & Err.Number
  End Sub

  Private Sub DoSomething()
  On Error GoTo A

      Err.Raise 5

  B:
      Debug.Print "Inside DoSomething[B]: " & Err.Number
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Raise Err.Number
      Exit Sub
  A:
      Debug.Print "Inside DoSomething[A]: " & Err.Number
      GoTo B 'resuming would clear the error and prevent rethrow
  End Sub
  ```

  This outputs:

  ```
  Inside DoSomething[A]: 5
  Inside DoSomething[B]: 5
  Inside Test[A]: 5
  ```

Depending on the exact reason why you would want to handle the same error in two different places, you could also consider making `B` a `Function` that returns a `Boolean` indicating success or failure - in that case `A` no longer handles an *error* per se, but rather uses normal flow control to determine what to do:

```
Public Sub Test()
On Error GoTo A
    If Not DoSomething Then
        Debug.Print "After DoSomething failed: " & Err.Number
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Exit Sub
A:
    Debug.Print "Inside Test[A]: " & Err.Number
End Sub

Private Function DoSomething() As Boolean
'Dim success As Boolean
On Error GoTo A

    Err.Raise 5
    'success = True

B:
    Debug.Print "Inside DoSomething[B]: " & Err.Number
    DoSomething = (Err.Number = 0) 'DoSomething = success
    Exit Function
A:
    Debug.Print "Inside DoSomething[A]: " & Err.Number
    'success = False
    GoTo B 'Resume B
End Function
```

Which produces this output:

```
Inside DoSomething[A]: 5
Inside DoSomething[B]: 5
After DoSomething failed: 0
```

Notice `Test` knows `DoSomething` failed, but `Err.Number` is 0. This is usually preferable to using runtime errors for flow control, again depending on your actual scenario. Also notice, the `GoTo` jump is avoidable in that situation, using a simple Boolean local variable to track your return value (the commented-out code).